# Definition of Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, self-learning

I found in a textbook this definition of expectation for a random variable $X$

$$E(X)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i-1}{\sqrt{n}}P\left(\frac{i-1}{\sqrt{n}}<X\leq \frac{i}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$

However, the textbook doesn't particularly mention where this definition comes from, when it's from, and how it's equivalent to the current definition to expectation.  Also, I cannot find any other references to this anywhere.  If anyone knows anywhere to further read about this, it would be highly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: If you are familiar with probability densities this is like a Riemann sum for $\int_0^{\sqrt{n}} x f(x) dx$. The weird use of square roots is to allow the upper limit of this "integration" to go to infinity. (This is not specific to continuous random variables, this is just the intuition.)

Comment: More generally you can look up essentially any reference on Lebesgue integration to find similar expressions.

Comment: I hope this is only for nonnegative random variables!

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes this is for only positive random variables I forgot to mention that!

Comment: @Ian The intuition makes sense for this, in a "hand wavy" way.  I'll read up a bit more on Lebesgue integration for now!  Thanks